# variables in inline assembly crashes

Tags: visual-c++, inline-assembly

the following piece of code works fine when i use it among some code

```
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[0x41154]  //Address
```

but when i try to set that address in my application as a varable and then do something like

```
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[PointerAddress]
```

the application crashes when the code is executed, `PointerAddress` is currently initialized as

```
DWORD    PointerAddress = 0x41154;
```

can anyone spot what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
[PointerAddress]
```

PointerAddress is treated as a pointer, not as a DWORD value.

It's like

```
*(DWORD*)PointerAddress
```

and not like

```
PointerAddress
```

You perform a double dereference, thus the crash.

Try using

```
mov eax, PointerAddress
mov ecx, dword ptr ds:[eax]
```